# How to develop (and print) a PCB starting from a logic scheme

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

I am currently working on a rather simple project: basically I have designed a circuit (only for the logic part, I have used logic.ly) that checks if 4 bits (that in my case are switches) represent a prime number, only using NAND gates.

Now I would really like to turn this into a custom PCB, but I don't know where to start.

I tried looking up on the internet (and I am sure that probably I have missed something,) but the only thing that I seem to be able to find are services to print fully developed circuits, so that means I have to figure out where, how and what electronic components I have to put in the circuit.

The problem is that I don't know anything about why and what resistances (for example) I should use in my circuit. Where do I start? Do you have any guide that I can refer to while designing the circuit?

Sorry if I've gone on too long, but I really don't know where to start.

Here is the logic.ly circuit for reference, if you want to take a look at it (sorry if the circuit looks disorganized, but it is one of the first that I designed.)

[image: Here's the circuit!]

Comment: Before turning it into a pcb, perhaps you could try wiring it on a breadboard with  NAND chips and switches.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :D
That is something I also considered, but doesn't the whole resistance and stuff persists?

Comment: Btw thanks to everyone editing my post, as you will probably have guessed, I don't speak english as my primary language :)

Comment: The circuit you have drawn may not work correctly when you build it with actual gates and actual switches. Your drawing leaves out a great deal of important detail. You need to build a prototype and make sure it works before trying to design a PCB.

Comment: Where are you planning to use resistances? I don't see any in the diagram. If you use chips like 74xx series or 40xx series, you don't need resistances to create nand gates. You may need pull up/down resistors to use with the switches. Their values are not so critical.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ElliotAlderson :D . What can I say, you have convinced me, I will try to build it on a breadboard. I wonder though what is the important detail I am missing :)

Comment: @AJN I don't know if I needed resistances, I got quite scared when I tried to look up simple circuits that I have studied (again, only the "logic" part) like full adders etc... because I saw a bunch of resistances, that's why I asked. I only have studied how to design the logic part of a simple circuit, and I don't have any hand on experience with actual logic components like the chips you mentioned. I will try to search up where can I buy some of those. Once again, thank for your response :D

Comment: When you have made your design, and know the ic’s you want to use, you can try starting with a simulation in software like lt spice. Then when it works in simulation, start drawing the design in a cad software, like kicad. Then when you have the design down in kicad, assign the footprints (what the ic’s look like) in kicad, so it knows what their sizes are. At last, design the PCB with the cad program. Order the pcb and components, solder it, and you’re good!

Answer (score 2):

First, consider which logic *family* you intend to use:

- **What DC power supply is available?** Some families are fussy (TTL requires +5V) while others are more tolerant (HCmos runs from +3V to +6V), (COSMOS from +3V to +18V).
- **What load must be driven?** Your pseudo-schematic shows a lamp as load. An incandescent lamp would require more current than most logic could supply. A LED could be driven more easily by most logic families, with a series resistor.
- **How are logic inputs generated?** Switches for this static design are simple, good input devices and won't need de-bouncing. But pull-up or pull-down resistors will be required. Resistor value depends on the logic family you choose.

Once a logic family is chosen, choose small-scale-logic chips from that family. You have some 2-input NAND gates, some 3-input NAND gates and one 4-input NAND gate. You'd like to use as few chips as possible.

For example, in TTL logic family, a 7400 chip contains four 2-input NAND gates. This one chip could fill the requirement for the four switch input inverters.
You also need four 3-input NANDs. A 7410 only contains three three-input NANDs. Do you need another 7410 for the fourth gate?
A hint: you only need three physical TTL chips to build this circuit, should you choose the TTL logic family.

---

**Logic input:**
Four Single-pole single-throw switches (SPST) can be used to generate logic high and logic low for this design:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3AnS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is better that an "activated" switch generates a logic low rather than logic high. In the schematic, all switches are shown "not-activated" - that is: open circuit. The associated 1k pull-up resistor generates a logic high in this case. When the switch is closed, the logic gate input is grounded, generating a logic low.

At the output, a logic gate drives a LED indicator. The series resistor value affects the LED brightness - a smaller-value resistor increases current and therefore brightness. The LED will light when logic output goes "low".

---

Consider building this circuit on a breadboard, to gain experience and confidence. Then attempt a printed circuit.
Remember that these schematics *do not show* supply connections, because they would add needless clutter. However, each logic chip you use has "Vcc" or "Vdd" supply pin, and a "GND" pin that must be wired to the DC supply. All logic should see the same DC supply: in the TTL examples shown here, this would be +5V.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Especially for all the components that you cited, now maybe I will be able to do something! :D

Answer (score 0):

This kind of picks up where @glen_geek left off.  Skip to the bottom for what I think is a better way.

1. **Make sure it works**  Experienced hands can just design a PC board for something like this and be pretty sure it'll work, or at least that it'll require a minimum of cuts and jumps to work.  A beginner can't.  My recommendation is that you

   - get a solderless breadboard and a power supply (or hack a USB cable and use an old phone charger -- that should give you a pretty reliable source of +5V)
   - Get at least a multimeter.  If you have money to fling around, get a cheap USB oscilloscope.  If not -- you'll want one eventually.
   - Get extra parts.  Particularly if you don't have that 'scope, having some spare LEDs that you can plug in (with load resistors!) to see what your circuit is doing is a bright* idea.
2. Find a circuit board layout program.

   - There are online PCB programs that make it easy, but they shield you from knowing how to do it "right".  They often also "shield" you from buying your finished board from the best source, by locking you into their suppliers.
   - KiCad and Eagle are the two most common "non-profit" PCB layout software packages out there.  **You will be confused** when you start using them.
3. Do one of:

   - Find a circuit board house.  "Circuit board aggregator" is the name to look for if you're on a budget.  "Fast turn circuit board" if you want to exchange $$$ for fast service.
   - Search on how to etch boards.  Personally, I think this is like building a car starting with iron ore and charcoal, but if you want to make inferior product and handle moderately hazardous chemicals at home -- go for it!  This will require that you get a boatload of materials, and learn a boatload of skills.
4. Have your board built (or build it)
5. Assemble it.
6. Find out it doesn't work (this even happens to the pros, although not usually with this simple of circuit).
7. Fix it.
8. Watch it work

**As an alternative**:

Lots of companies that sell solderless breadboards also sell *solderable* breadboards with the same connection pattern (e.g. [this one from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12070)).  Some of these are high enough quality that I've built one-off circuits on them for clients, without feeling like I've short-changed them.  If your goal is something that works, and using these boards doesn't result in something too big, and you're only doing one, you'll save yourself a tremendous amount of work by using a solderless breadboard and just putting the equipment into service.

* Couldn't resist

Comment: nice joke, ahahah! Thanks for the answer!